# jQuery If one element is visible, close the other one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if there is a way to hide an element after another element becomes visible. Here is my jQuery code right now

```
var fade = $("#listofeffects ul:nth-of-type(2)");
var firstchild = $("#listofeffects ul:first-child");

  firstchild.click(function(){
   $(".element1").fadeToggle();
    });

    fade.click(function(){
   $(".element2").fadeToggle();
    });
```

When **.element1** is visible, **.element2** can't be shown. I have researched using if/else javascript statements, but haven't found anything that works. I have also looked into using :visible and :hidden, which hasn't worked either.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your HTML has different `events` attached to 2 different `<ul>`'s,

```
  var firstchild  = $("#listofeffects ul:first-child");
  var fade        = $("#listofeffects ul:nth-of-type(2)");
  $('.element2').hide();         // initially show only .element1    

  $("#listofeffects").on('click','ul',function(e){
      $('.element1,.element2').hide();
      ( $(e.currentTarget).is(firstchild) ) ? $('.element1').fadeIn('slow') : $('.element2').fadeIn('slow') ;
  });
```

[see demo](http://codepen.io/CreativeCreate/pen/NNMBVj?editors=1010)

Answer (score 4):

Try This.
First Hide All Elements on click and after show clicked element using jQuery(this)

eg:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var ulchild = jQuery("#listofeffects ul");
    ulchild.click(function(){
        jQuery("#listofeffects ul").hide("slow");
        jQuery(this).show(slow);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is like this

```
<div class="div1 divClass"> Div 1 text </div>
<div class="div2 divClass"> Div 2 text </div>
<div class="div3 divClass"> Div 3 text </div>
<div class="div4 divClass"> Div 4 text </div>
```

Jquery code to do this.

```
$(".divClass").click(function(){
   $(this).siblings().addClass("hide");
});
```

This jquery code will show that clicked element and other elements will be hided automatically...